# Mobile Automation Test with Appium and Saucelabs

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, appium

I'm a newbie on Appium and Saucelabs. If I understand correctly, the test script must be executed on my machine and the commands are sent in Saucelabs cloud, step by step (via http). If this assumption is correctly, can I executed script for iOS and Android on Windows machine? Mac OSX is required for iOS test?

Answer (score 0):

Appium Studio is an IDE that lets you run iOS or Android on any machine.  Mac OSX is not required fr iOS test with Appium.  https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/datasheet/

Are you testing a native app or web app?  I work for Testim that helps automate testing.  We can emulate the devices from Chrome driver for web app testing.  We recently came out with an easy free tool that enables you to record tests and then copy the code that can run on your Playwrite testing framework.

https://www.producthunt.com/posts/testim-s-playwright-recorder-playground

Check it out and let us know how you like it.